# Where to add members of java classes

Tags: java, class, object

Implement a class Student. For the purpose of this exercise, a student has a name and a total quiz score. Supply an appropriate constructor and methods `getName()`, `addQuiz(int score)`, `getTotalScore()`, and `getAverageScore()`. To compute the latter, you also need to store the number of quizzes that the student took.

...

I am having an especially hard time with the scores and name. Do I add the scores to both the `Student.java` and the `StudentTester.java` files or only the tester? I cannot figure this out.

Here is my code:

```
/** A student has taken a number of quizzes and has an average score 
based on the quizzes that were taken.
*/

public class Student
{

  private String name;
  private double totalscore;
  private int numquiz;
  }

// Constructs a student object with the name "MccStudent" and with zero total of quiz scores

 public Student(String "mccStudent")
{
  this.name = studentname;
  numquiz = 0;
  totalscore = 0;

}

public String getName() 
{
    return name;
    }


// Adds the number of quizzes taken

public void addQuiz(double quizscore)
{
 totalscore+=quizscore;
 numquiz++; 
 } 

 // Returns the total quiz score

public double getTotalScore () 
 { 
 return totalscore; 
 } 

// Returns the avaerage grade

 public double getAverageScore () 
 { 
 return totalscore/numquiz; 
 } 
 }​

/** Create a class to test the Student class.
*/
public class StudentTester
{
   /** 
   Tests the methods of the Student class.
   */

  public static void main(String[] args)

  {
  // Create an object
  Student mccStudent = new Student();

  mccStudent.addQuiz(100);
  mccStudent.addQuiz(80);
  mccStudent.addQuiz(95);
  mccStudent.addQuiz(97);

  System.out.println(mccStudent.getName());

  System.out.println(mccStudent.getTotalScore());

  // Display average quiz score

   System.out.println(mccStudent.getAverage.Score());
   }

 }​
```

Comment: is your code compiling?

Comment: Without running it myself the general idea looks good though here and there might be some syntax errors. But I can't really figure out what you are asking. Is is about where to add the score? Then it seems ok the way you did it.

Comment: Yes, mainly about where to add the score, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all try to understand what Constructor is. Here is oracle documentation with nice examples: [Constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html). Ill write simple example for you. Student is new Object that has String name attribute.

```
public class Student {

  public String name; //name of student

  public Student(String name) {//Constructor for student, receiving name when u create new object Student
    this.name = name; //set received name to this public String name
  }


  /**
   * When u call this method you will get inputed name from constructor
   * so if u call Student stud = new Student("John");
   * new Student("John") is constructor!
   * with stud.getName(); you will get "John".
   * This is called getter.
   * @return name of student
   */
  public String getName() {
      return name;
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some major issues here, for one the first brace is closed after declaring your instance variables, so the rest of the code for Student is out of scope. Remove the first close brace, and that should help that.

Another issue is the way you are using your constructor (the part that says public Student(String "mccstudents")). You need to  providing a variable name there, and then whenever you make a new object, you pass in a string, and that will take the place of the variable name.

Not to sound like one of your teaches, you really shouldn't leave this to last minute To jump the gun on any number of people who will write a reply for this, this site is designed to help specific issues, not analyse the whole program.

Are there particular issues and concepts that you are not understanding that I can help with?

Comment: I fixed that, thank you. Now I have only 2 errors instead of more than 20.

I know, I apologize. I have been working on it for a few days but I am having a hard time understanding it. I watched some tutorials so I am understanding it better, but because of work and my other classes, I barely have enough time to absorb what I study. Sorry again.

Is the assignment telling me to only stick with "getName", "addQuiz", "getTotalScore" and "getAverageScore" or is it alright that I used things like "numquiz", "totalscore"?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with changing the names of the functions, as long as they do as the assignment specifies. Adding get to the start of the function names is a convention that is often used in these types of functions, known as accessors, or getters. I think all the assignment is asking is for you to add the functionality to these methods (you seem to be on the right track there), which shouldn't take too long if you understand how to structure the code. Good work with fixing the errors, keep it up!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @KaiMattern After reading the linked article, that all makes sense. Hopefully not too long until I at that point, but until then I shall keep it in mind. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You add the fields to the class itself (`Student.java`).

Only code that performs tests should appear in the test class (`StudentTester.java`).